# Display mouse cordinates on jPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, mouseevent, paint

I want to display mouse cordinates using drawString() method when I move the mouse. Here is my current code. This works for mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) method but not for mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) method. Can someone help me with this please?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test extends JFrame {

    public Test() {
        PaintLocaion paintlocation = new PaintLocaion();
        paintlocation.setSize(400,300);
        add(paintlocation, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);       
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test().setVisible(true);
    }

    private class PaintLocaion extends JPanel {
        int x, y;

        public PaintLocaion() {          
            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                    x = e.getX();
                    y = e.getY();
                    repaint();
                }
            });
        }      

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            super.paint(g);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.drawString(x + ", " + y, 10, 10);
        }
    }     
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of registering a `MouseListener` you need to register a `MouseMotionListener`...

```
public PaintLocaion() {          
    addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
            x = e.getX();
            y = e.getY();
            repaint();
        }
    });
}
```

See [How to write a Mouse-Motion Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousemotionlistener.html) for more details

**Updated from comments by mKorbel**

There are issues with overriding `paint`, while it might seem like the logical thing to do, the area begin updated by the `paint` method may not be update when a repaint occurs and you can end up with some weird paint issues.

It's recommended to use `paintComponent` instead.

If you're trying to paint over the top components, you might consider using the glass pane or `JXLayer`/`JLayer` instead

Take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details about the paint process.  [How to use root panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) for details about the glass pane and [How to Decorate Components with the JLayer Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html)

Comment: @Lahiru Kavinda and to repace paint() with paintComponent

Comment: @mKorbel I was trying not to scroll that far down :P

Answer (score 2):

you can try to use `MouseMotionListener` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousemotionlistener.html